# Adding additional data(watermark) to epub files for better security

Tags: security, watermark, epub

We would like to publish some ebooks(epub files) and sell them through our web shop. We would like to be able to "track" these ebooks by adding some information(example: name of the customer) to the file. I have read that some people are putting comments in jpegs etc. or trying to hide the information between  tags. I wonder if there are any other, or better solutions? I was thinking of putting the MD5 hash of the customer ID or something similar, but i don't know where should it go.
I know that experienced users can strip these solutions out easily, but i am trying to come up with some sort of solution for the average user. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a form of [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).  [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/230915/geek-to-live--hide-data-in-files-with-easy-steganography-tools) has some tips on this.

Comment: Thanks, great links to solve my problem.(Sorry for the late reply.)